# Redeclaring variables in different scopes

Tags: javascript, scope

I happened across some JavaScript today which looks like this:

```
var x = "abc";
var y = true;

if (y) {
    var x = "xyz";
}

alert(x);
```

As a Perl developer, this looked like a bug as `x` is redeclared in a tighter scope and the assigned value should be lost. However, on testing, the code appears to be working as expected.

Is the `var` ignored and the original scope maintained if a variable is redeclared like this?

Comment: if blocks do not have a different scope in javascript

Comment: `x` will just be redeclared yes.

Comment: i think, this info is very basic, and can be found in any book about js. it's question not for stack overflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript only has function scope, not block scope. The second `var x =` is treated as an ordinary assignment, as if it were just `x =`, because the variable has already been declared.

Comment: in javascript 1.7 you will be able to use 'let' instead of 'var' to declare a variable in block scope.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

Comment: To add, in javascript, it is not an error to have a variable declared twice. The second declaration is ignored but if there is an assignment, only the assignment is considered.

Answer (score 0):

In JS there is only global (window) and functional scope.

```
var x = 1;
function a() { var x = 2; return x; }

alert(x); //1
alert(window.x); //1
alert(a()); //2
```

Even if you define variable inside block, it will exist in whole scope

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var k = i+1;
}

alert(i);  //10
alert(window.k);  //10
```

edit: because of this, good JS code defines its variables at the beginning of each scope

```
var i,j,max = 10;

function a() {
    var i,j,k;
    for (i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        j = i * 2;
        k = i / 2;
    }
    return i * j * k;
}

i = a();
j = a() * 2;
```